# Set text by multiple span styles by iterating fails

Tags: android, text, styles, spannablestring

I set few words by multiple span styles and when I pass array with styles to method, in the result only the last word has that styles. It ommits the other words. Why? Below my code and execution. Thank You in advance.

```
//execution in code
charSequence = SpannableUtils.format(
        charSequence,
        new ParcelableSpan[]{new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)},//or more
        new String[]{"Test1", "Test2"}
);

//method
public static CharSequence format(CharSequence charSequence, ParcelableSpan[] spans, String[] words) {
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(charSequence);

    for (String word : words) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(word));
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(charSequence);

        for (ParcelableSpan span : spans) {
            while (matcher.find()) {
                ssb.setSpan(span, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    }

    return ssb;
}
```

However if I check type of span with 'instance of' and then I create new constructior it works. Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot apply the same span object multiple times. All previously set spans get discarded, thus only the last word has the span.

If you want to reuse it, you have to copy it with [`CharacterStyle.wrap()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html#wrap%28android.text.style.CharacterStyle%29) before you apply it:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    ssb.setSpan(CharacterStyle.wrap(span), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

Comment: how did you find the way that it was the solution? I read documentation and samples and characterstyle is very rare with codesample. BTW. thank You.

Comment: @deadfish I once had the same issue, found it somewhere.